# Print from dictionary

Tags: python

Given this dictionary:

```
   info = {'building': 'Mirafiori',
   'rooms': [{'name': 'Z1', 'sensor_id': 's_Z1_DHT11', 'sensor_present': True},
   {'name': 'Z2', 'sensor_id': 's_Z2_DHT11', 'sensor_present': True},
   {'name': 'Z3', 'sensor_id': 's_Z3_DHT11', 'sensor_present': True},
   {'name': 'Z4', 'sensor_id': None, 'sensor_present': False},
   {'name': 'Z5', 'sensor_id': 's_Z5_DHT11', 'sensor_present': True},
   {'name': 'Z6', 'sensor_id': None, 'sensor_present': False}]
```

How can I print a list of the rooms?
Desired ouput: `['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z5', 'Z6']`

Answer (score 2):

You need the `'name'` of each room in `'rooms'`:

```
[room['name'] for room in info['rooms']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `room` elements within your `info` dictionary and access their names like the following:

```py
list_of_rooms = [room["name"] for room in info["rooms"]]
print(list_of_rooms)
```

Comment: Please include an explanation